# Проблема с точками в мыле django-registration

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, использую у себя в проекте **django-registration**, в связи с тем, что на сайте можно использовать пробную версию на софт, мне надо, чтоб у кажого юзера был уникальный e-mail. Использую форму **RegistrationFormNoFreeEmail(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail)**
И долгое время проблем не замечал, как вдруг один из пользователей написал, что при регистрации, можно всего лишь добавить точку в адресс (н-р. email@example.com, e.mail@example.com). Сталкивался кто-то с данной проблеммой, и , если сталкивался, как проблема решалась?

Comment: А в чём проблема? e.mail@example.com и email@example.com - это разные адреса.

Comment: К примеру, у меня есть аккаунт e.mail@example.com. Если при регистрации указать e.m.ail@example.com, письмо с активацией придет на e.mail@example.com. Вне зависимости от того, зарегистрирован ли ранее другой пользователь на e.mail@example.com

Comment: django-registration 2.2 не наблюдаю такой проблемы. Подозреваю, что проблема в почтовом сервере получателя.

Comment: Я использую django-registration 2.0. Отправка идет через smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Неважно через что идёт отправка, важно через что получается. Я могу свой почтовый сервер так настроить, чтобы он принимал письма на любой адрес, а потом зарегистрировать на любом сайте любое количество учёток.

Comment: В дополнение к сказанному; например, gmail письма, адресованные на `e.m.a.i.l+anything@gmail.com`, доставит на `email@gmail.com`. Но с точки зрения стандарта — это разные адреса, и на какой-нибудь другом почтовом сервере такие адреса могут принадлежать разным пользователям.